# Hosting one application with multiple vanity routes

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, rewrite, asp.net, iis-8.5

## Problem

We currently have two ASP.NET MVC projects being served up from a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 like so:

- `foo` hosted on `server.com/foo`
- `bar` hosted on `server.com/bar`

However, the code of these projects is nearly identical so we're in the process of consolidating them. Ideally, we'd have

- `common` hosted on `server.com/common` (which would only be used internally)
- IIS rewrite rule `^foo(.*)$` → `common{R:1}` so it *appears* to be hosted on `server.com/foo`
- IIS rewrite rule `^bar(.*)$` → `common{R:1}` so it *appears* to be hosted on `server.com/bar`

We've set up the new common project and it's working fine on `server.com/common`, however, when we enabled the rewrite rules, anything trying to navigate to `server.com/foo` or `/bar` will produce a 403 error, specifically:

[image: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied]

## Troubleshooting

I'm pretty sure this is not an issue with my pattern/replacement strings, because if I change the rule type to `Redirect`, it produces the desired destination URL.

If I create a IIS rewrite rule `^common/test(.*)$` → `common{R:1}` then the `common` code runs correctly, but `^common-test(.*)$` → `common{R:1}` fails, so there's *something* preventing `common` from being served from any URL *other than* `/common`.

What's confusing here is that there is another application which does a similar thing with `/baz` and `/qux` being rewritten to a shared application, `/other`. If I point `^foo(.*)$` → `other{R:1}` it works fine (though of course, it executes the wrong application code). I'm unable to identify any other relevant differences between these two applications that would cause this. In fact, I copied nearly all the `Web.config` file from `other` and still saw the same behavior.

I've also exhausted these other potential solutions:

- [IIS URL Rewrite : 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37720882/1715579) - Require SSL is disabled site-wide; we handle SSL at the ingress. Also, for all of these applications, we only use anonymous authentication.
- [Unable to get anything except 403 from a .Net 4.5 website](https://serverfault.com/a/405585/207362) - I enabled this option and didn't see any change.

What else could be causing this? I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Hi, does the iis error log show anything usefull for the 403 error ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 None that I've been able to find. This server hosts a large number of applications and the logs folder doesn't make it obvious which log file is for which application. I enabled *log rewritten URL* hoping I could grep for it, but no such luck. If it is creating logs, I haven't found them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a bit more and conferring again with the developers behind `other`, I think we've figured out this issue.

Basically, the site hosting `server.com` and **all** the applications under it that will be participating in the rewrite (`common`, as well as `foo` and `bar` until we are ready to delete them) need to be running in the same IIS app pool.

I've adjusted our deployment process to account for this. We use Octopus, so it boiled down to just changing one variable in each project. For future readers, your process is probably different, but just in case, hopefully this helps someone else:

[image: Project Variables]